# undo-kill-buffer and save-place-mode

Tags: kill-buffer, saveplace

I use this function to reopen a file killed by mistake.

```el
(defun undo-kill-buffer ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((active-files (loop for buf in (buffer-list)
                              when (buffer-file-name buf) collect it)))
      (loop for file in recentf-list
            unless (member file active-files) return (find-file file))))
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-x K") 'undo-kill-buffer)
```

The problem is that I would like to reopen the file at the right place (`save-place-mode`) only in this case. If I open a file with another function (`find-file`, `find-alternate-file`, `find-file-at-point`, ...) I don't want to remember the last position.

I have not found a solution to activate save-place-mode in some cases only.
Is it possible to write a `find-file-with-saveplace` function without modify `find-file` ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the source for `save-place--setup-hooks`, since you want a subset of this behavior. I haven't tested this out, but I believe you want:

- `(add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook #'save-place-to-alist)` so that the place is saved when a buffer is killed.
- Modify your undo command to call `save-place-find-file-hook` after it calls `find-file`, with the restored buffer as the current buffer.

*Update*: The `save-place-to-alist` function checks whether save-place is set, so you probably need your own function here too:

```
(defun always-save-place-to-alist ()
  (let ((save-place t))
    (save-place-to-alist)))

(add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook #'always-save-place-to-alist)
```

And the hook that restores the position also enables save-place, so you probably want this too:

```
(defun restore-save-place ()
  (save-place-find-file-hook)
  (setq save-place nil))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesn't works. Despite the hook, the place is not recorded after killing buffers.